# OCMock doesn't stub NSBundle method

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, nsbundle, xctest, ocmock

I'm using since recently OCMock for my unit testing. I need to stub the 
`objectForInfoDictionaryKey:` method from `NSBundle`. I've done the following :

```
self.bundleMock = OCMClassMock([NSBundle class]);
OCMStub([self.bundleMock objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"GITHash"]).andReturn(@"c424242");
;
```

Here is the call I wanna stub :

```
NSString * appHashString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"GITHash"];
```

But nothing seem to be stubbed, at runtime I still have the "correct" value.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could be misremembering, but I think you need to use `partialMockForObject` to mock the instance returned by `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, instead of mocking the class `NSBundle` because `objectForInfoDictionaryKey` is an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I didn't noticed this method before !

Comment: So instead of the code in the question, I use what exactly?

Comment: See the documentation here - http://ocmock.org/reference/#partial-mocks


In keeping with the original question's code:
`self.bundleMock = OCMPartialMock([NSBundle mainBundle]);
OCMStub([self.bundleMock objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"GITHash"]).andReturn(@"c424242");`


This mocks the instance so that calling an instance method returns the stubbed return value.